# Why does Relay.QL result in unterminated string constant error?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

The following code results in an "Unterminated string constant" error, and I'm not sure why. This code is from [this blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/19/building-the-facebook-news-feed-with-relay.html) from the Facebook React team.

```
import React from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';

// Story.react.js
class Story extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var story = this.props.story;
    return (
      <Story>
        <Image uri={story.author.profile_picture.uri} />
        <Text>{story.author.name}</Text>
        <Text>{story.text}</Text>
      </Story>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Relay.createContainer(Story, {
  queries: {
    story: Relay.QL`
      Story {
        author {
          name,
          profile_picture {
            uri
          }
        },
        text
      }
    `
  }
});
```

If I replace

```
Relay.QL`
  ...
`
```

with `{}`, the error goes away (but, of course, so does the data).

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we originally wrote those examples we simplified the syntax to avoid distracting people with extraneous details, especially because we knew that some of that syntax would change before the open source release.

To fix this:

- Return the `Relay.QL` template literal from a function.
- The `queries` property is now `fragments`.
- Fragment declaration syntax has changed, so `Story` is now `fragment on Story`.
- Fields are camel-cased, so `profile_picture` would become `profilePicture`.
- (Optional) Drop the commas, as they are considered to be whitespace by GraphQL.
- Additionally, make sure that you're processing your source code through the babel-relay-plugin, which it the thing responsible for taking that template literal and turning it into a representation of the fragment annotated with data that Relay needs at runtime; an example showing one way to do this can be found in [the relay-starter-kit](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit).

```
module.exports = Relay.createContainer(Story, {
  queries: {
    story: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Story {
        author {
          name
          profilePicture {
            uri
          }
        }
        text
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

I think we should [go back and update the syntax](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5235) in the blog post to avoid potential confusion, but in the meantime I think you're better off looking at [the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: Straight from the source... this is awesome, thanks. I was actually trying to merge the example in the blog post with the relay-starter-kit, just as an exercise, and was totally confused by conflicting syntaxes.